# Is paid Apple Developer Program subscription required to distribute test IPA file?

Tags: ios, developer-program, mobile-device-management, code-signing

I am building an Ionic app, and I want to distribute it to a few people in my organization.

Ionic Cordova iOS build command runs successfully. Now i need to generate the IPA file to install the app on iOS devices.

When I am running Product → Archive in Xcode Menu, it gives code signing error.

My queries are:

1. How to get the IPA file? Does it need paid subscription to the Apple Developer Program?
2. Best solution to distribute to app to a limited number of people?
3. Getting signing error?

   ```
   Code Signing Error: app has conflicting provisioning settings. app is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. 

   Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

   Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.1'
   ```

Comment: Do you have physical access to the said devices?

Comment: yes , i can access  all the device

Comment: In that case, it's best to connect the devices to your development machine, build for running and get the app on devices. With the free developer account, you are not entitled to create distributable IPA.

Comment: in this case dont i need any subscription ? just build one by one to every device right?

Comment: so i just build the app for user device and they can use it for free. So this manually installed app have any expiry?can we continue the same process for live environment?

Comment: You don't need a paid subscription. Simply connect the devices and go to Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme..., under Run, change the build configuration to Release and select Wait for executable to be launched corresponding to "Launch". Now simply run the app with the device connected and selected as the run destination. You may run into some limitations such as the build expiring in 7 days or limit on number of devices you can run the app on (I don't recall what the upper limit is).

Comment: Manually installed apps expires in about 7 days IIRC. I don't recall correctly, but there's a cap on the max. number of devices you can simultaneously install the app on. The intent of this provision is so that non-paid members can test their app on a real device. This facility is not provided by Apple Developer Program keeping distribution in mind.

Comment: if after 7 days app expires so no use of live app. For permanent solution i need to buy enterprise program even if i have 3-4 users for the app in organisation.

Comment: You can also distribute apps for internal use using normal Apple Developer Program.

Answer (score 1):

So as a new iOS developer i found three way for building and distributing app.

1. For app store distribution normal developer license can work.
2. For in House apps you can buy enterprise edition license. With this you
   can distribute app via MDM and [diawi](https://diawi.com) when you want to
   distribute .ipa file of your app.
3. If you have limited in house
   users and have physical access to those devices you can directly
   install app via xcode in the device.